# replaceAll() converting %23 with # to &num; in java

Tags: java, spring-boot

which using the following replaceAll() method: String url = url.replaceAll( "%23", "#");

Output: https://org.com/&num/ABC/search

we are getting # symbol in reposnse instead of #, could you please help whats the correspoing conversion for this. Thanks in advance.

Expected output: https://org.com/#/ABC/search

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: can you add the input url?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`URLDecoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html). It will sort problems for all the encoded values.

```java
String res = URLDecoder.decode(url, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

//input : https://org.com/%23/ABC/search
//output: https://org.com/#/ABC/search
```

Comment: tried with URLDecoder, still it converts to &num instead of #

Comment: You should check your url properly then . Try to print or debug to see what is the actual value it's returning . I don't think it's an issue with replaceall or urldecoder